# How to paint a displaced bar in ASP.NET Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, webforms, asp.net-4.5

I am using `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` and trying to paint displaced bars, but instead of this way:
[image]
this other way:
[image]

I mean, I would like to paint the bar starting in the point 1 and displaced 55px to the right.

I have achieved this:
[image]

with the following code:

```
Chart1.Series.Clear();

    int[,] horas = new int[,] { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 4, 0 }, { 5, 1 }, { 6, 0 }, { 7, 0 }, { 8, 1 }, { 9, 1 } };
    Chart1.DataSource = horas;
    var series1 = new Series
    {
        Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
        IsVisibleInLegend = false,
        IsXValueIndexed = true,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeColumn,
    };
    series1["PixelPointWidth"] = "1";

    int[,] horas1 = new int[,] { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 4, 0 }, { 5, 1 }, { 6, 0 }, { 7, 0 }, { 8, 1 }, { 9, 1 } };
    var series2 = new Series
    {
        Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
        IsVisibleInLegend = false,
        IsXValueIndexed = true,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeColumn
    };
    series2["PixelPointWidth"] = "110";

    for (int i = 0; i < horas.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        series1.Points.AddXY(horas[i, 0], horas[i, 1]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < horas.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        series2.Points.AddXY(horas1[i, 0], horas1[i, 1]);
    }

    int b = 0;
    foreach (var label in Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels)
    {
        label.Text = b.ToString();
        b++;
    }

    Chart1.Series.Add(series1);
    Chart1.Series.Add(series2);

    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 0;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;

    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
    Chart1.DataBind();
```

But this is not an optimal solution as I must paint at least 1 pixel in the side I don't want.

I would appreciate any solution or suggestion on how to achieve my goal.
Thx in advance.

Edit. This is working in a Windows Server 2012 under IIS 6.0 developed with VS 2015 Professional in the NET 4.5 Framework

Edit: I mean 55 px to the right, but the best solution would be to the next point in the X axis

Edit: this is the content of web.config.

```html
    <configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
          assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What's asp.net chart? I'm guessing your using a graph library. Without this piece of information no one can help

Comment: @Liam the class is: System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

Comment: I'm guessing this is a web forms control? I'm struggling to find any references to how this works (or what it is apart from a net class). What version of .net is this? Have you installed any plugins? Basically we need a full [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with **all** the relevant information here.

Comment: @Liam thx, edited with the .net version, and IIS version. No plugins in the application.

Comment: I've added the web forms tag as I'm guessing this is webforms and you haven't actually clarified this. The server config and visual studio version isn't relevant. This still doesn't constitute an MCVE for me so I'm leaving my vote to close.

Comment: @Liam, this is a website, i am adding more information to clarify everythin. Sorry, but it's my first asp application so i am still learning about this world.

Comment: My suggest is to use a graph library.

Comment: @Emanuele  thx, do you know any graph library for this purpouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to paint displaced chart bars, you should simply shift the axis labels by using `CustomLabels`.

[image]

**ASPX:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="600px" Width="800px" >
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        <AxisY>
                            <MajorGrid LineColor="DarkGray" LineDashStyle="Dot" />
                        </AxisY>
                        <AxisX>
                            <MajorGrid LineColor="DarkGray" LineDashStyle="Dot" />
                        </AxisX>
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CS:**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[,] horas = new int[,] { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 4, 0 }, { 5, 1 }, { 6, 0 }, { 7, 0 }, { 8, 1 }, { 9, 1 } };

        var series1 = new Series
        {
            Color = Color.Green,
            IsVisibleInLegend = false,
            IsXValueIndexed = true,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeColumn,
            CustomProperties = "PointWidth=0.8"
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < horas.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            series1.Points.AddXY(horas[i, 0], horas[i, 1]);
        }

        Chart1.Series.Add(series1);

        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel { FromPosition = 0, ToPosition = 1, Text = "0", GridTicks = GridTickTypes.All });
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel { FromPosition = 1, ToPosition = 2, Text = "1", GridTicks = GridTickTypes.All });
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel { FromPosition = 2, ToPosition = 3, Text = "2", GridTicks = GridTickTypes.All });
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel { FromPosition = 3, ToPosition = 4, Text = "3", GridTicks = GridTickTypes.All });
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel { FromPosition = 4, ToPosition = 5, Text = "4", GridTicks = GridTickTypes.All });
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel { FromPosition = 5, ToPosition = 6, Text = "5", GridTicks = GridTickTypes.All });
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel { FromPosition = 6, ToPosition = 7, Text = "6", GridTicks = GridTickTypes.All });
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel { FromPosition = 7, ToPosition = 8, Text = "7", GridTicks = GridTickTypes.All });
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel { FromPosition = 8, ToPosition = 9, Text = "8", GridTicks = GridTickTypes.All });
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel { FromPosition = 9, ToPosition = 10, Text = "9", GridTicks = GridTickTypes.All });
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel { FromPosition = 10, ToPosition = 11, Text = "10", GridTicks = GridTickTypes.All });
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! that was what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a Graph/Chart library as:

1. Google (https://developers.google.com/chart/)
2. FusionCharts (https://www.fusioncharts.com/)
3. Chartjs (http://www.chartjs.org/)
4. D3js (https://d3js.org/)